# Redirect .php extension requests to same url without .php

Tags: apache, .htaccess, migration

I've migrated a website. The previous website was built in php, so all the links in search have a php extension. The pages on the new website were built with static NuxtJS and do not.

All the resources I've found are for hiding .php from urls, but how can I use the .htaccess file to 301 redirect all .php urls to ones without them.

Take this:

```
https://example.com/about.php
```

and turn it into this:

```
https://example.com/about
```

before it hits the server and gives the visitor a 500 or 404 error?

Answer (score 0):

Found something that works well enough

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .php$
RewriteRule ^(.*).php$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

This turns

```
https://example.com/about.php
```

into

```
https://example.com/about/
```

I'd prefer if the redirect did not contain the ' / ' at the end, but I suppose this fixes the breaking changes for now.

I placed this rewrite before the non-www and https redirects that I currently have.

Comment: "I'd prefer if the redirect did not contain the ' / ' at the end" - The directive you posted does not do that, so _something else_ would seem to be doing that (possibly as a 2nd redirect?). In the rule you posted, the _condition_ (`RewriteCond` directive) is superfluous.